# Grafana Nested Panels

Tags: layout, grafana

I've been trying to modify Grafana to suit one of my recent needs. Is there any possibility to restructure Panels in Grafana to look something like the image below?

[Grafana completely flexible structure/layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKnYs.png)

It really does not have to look like the one above, but if there is at least a quick way to get something like the one below, I'd really be thankful:

[Grafana Nested panels (two or more child panels inside a parent panel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtrLs.png)

Even if it means that I have to tweak the SDK, a small sample of the process flow would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thats not really possible..

Grafana dashboards contains rows with panels. Panels can have a set width and height.

Here is a dashboard example of how to have panels with fixed width and height: http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/advanced-layout

Comment: Oh snap! Really thought it would at least contain some kinda base to construct a set of nested panels, in which case much more flexible applications could be built. I do not deny the fact that it does have a really rich amount of features, but then, there's always one drawback or limitation that makes you take a step back, specially when time's a constraint.

Comment: Thanks Carl! If you do know of a system which allows something similar to the first image I attached with my original post, and is both responsive and as feature rich or almost similar to Grafana, please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not aware of any system like that. At least not in the open source space where I belong :)

Comment: I'd actually like to see nested rows specifically. Simply so I can have a toggleable hide/show for a row containing other rows which can also be toggled to show or hid. Think it's worth a feature request, or are there other options to achieve the same thing?

Comment: That advanced layout link appears to have tiles stacked above each other within a panel. Is that using the new Grafana 5 grid layout, or is there some trick in pre-5 Grafana to make a nested panel or something, other than embedding an HTML panel with a nested dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it appeared first at my google search results so i'll post what i've found here.
There's "convert to row" option for panels, which can be used like this:
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860

This fully covers my personal demands

Comment: Your answer is just a link?. Please consider adding more details to it, of what exactly fixed your issue.

Comment: I've already provided all needed info, read carefully:
"There's "convert to row" option for panels"

After that i've provided link for dashboard where u can see how it behaves on real example (by improting or just opening screenshot)